# Como enviar uma mensagem para uma room especifica com Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Como que eu faço para enviar uma mensagem para uma especifica room? 
tipo:

server.js

```
io.in('roomA').on('msg', function(msg) {
...
});
```

client.js

```
io.in('roomA').emit('msg, 'Hi');
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/emit.md), para mandar uma mensagem para uma sala específica podes usar o exemplo abaixo:

```
//enviando para todos na sala (room) 'game', com exceção do remetente
socket.to('game').emit('nice game', "let's play a game");

// enviando para todos na sala (room) 'game', incluindo o remetente
io.in('game').emit('big-announcement', 'the game will start soon');
```